# PageList.size is always zero

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-paging

Actually, I am new to [Paging Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/). Here is situation, i'm observing [PagedList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedList) from my [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel) which is always returning zero even news list appeared on UI.

```
 viewModel.getNews().observe(this, news -> {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    Timber.d("news size is %s",news.size());// **news size is 0**
                    adapter.submitList(news);
                });
```

My DataSource is

```
public class NewsDataSource extends ItemKeyedDataSource<String, News> {

    private MutableLiveData<Resource.Status> netStatusLive = new MutableLiveData<>();

   /*Hide Logic for clean purpose*/

    private List<News> localNewsList = new ArrayList<>();

    public NewsDataSource( /*Hide Logic for clean purpose*/) {
         /*Hide Logic for clean purpose*/
    }


    @Override
    public void loadInitial(@NonNull LoadInitialParams<String> params, @NonNull LoadInitialCallback<News> callback) {
        netStatusLive.postValue(Resource.Status.LOADING);
        localNewsList.clear();
        Disposable disposable =  /*Hide Logic for clean purpose*/

        compositeDisposable.add(disposable);
    }

    @Override
    public void loadAfter(@NonNull LoadParams<String> params, @NonNull LoadCallback<News> callback) {
        if (localNewsList.size() > 19) {
            netStatusLive.postValue(Resource.Status.LOADING);
            Disposable disposable =  /*Hide Logic for clean purpose*/
            compositeDisposable.add(disposable);
        }

    }

    private String getLastIdOfNews(List<News> localNewsList) {
        if (localNewsList.size() <= 0) {
            return "android";
        } else {
            return localNewsList.get(localNewsList.size() - 1).getId();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void loadBefore(@NonNull LoadParams<String> params, @NonNull LoadCallback<News> callback) {
        //do nothing...
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String getKey(@NonNull News item) {
        return item.getId();
    }

    private void onPaginationError(Throwable throwable) {
        netStatusLive.postValue(Resource.Status.ERROR);
        Timber.e(throwable);
    }

    public LiveData<Resource.Status> getNetworkState() {
        return netStatusLive;
    }

}
```

In this case `localNewsList` is require to give last id of News on `loadAfter` which is like

```
Observable<List<News>> getNewsList(@Query("skip") int skip,
                                            @Query("limit") int limit,
                                            @Query("lastNewsId") String lastNewsId);
```

My DataSourceFactory is

```
    public class NewsDataSourceFactory extends DataSource.Factory<String, Journal> {
        private MutableLiveData<JournalDataSource> dataSourceLive = new MutableLiveData<>();

         /*Hide Logic for clean purpose*/

        public NewsDataSourceFactory( /*Hide Logic for clean purpose*/) {
             /*Hide Logic for clean purpose*/
        }

        @Override
        public DataSource<String, Journal> create() {
            JournalDataSource dataSource = new JournalDataSource( /*Hide Logic for clean purpose*/);
            dataSourceLive.postValue(dataSource);
            return dataSource;

        }
 public void prepareData(String coursId, String studnetId) {
        this.coursId = coursId;
        this.studnetId = studnetId;
    }


        public MutableLiveData<JournalDataSource> getDataSource() {
            return dataSourceLive;
        }
    }
```

ViewModle is

```
public class NewsViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private LiveData<PagedList<News>> newslist = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private LiveData<Resource.Status> networkState = new MutableLiveData<>();

    private NewsDataSourceFactory factory;

    private PagedList.Config config;

    private Executor executor;


    NewsViewModel(NewsDataSourceFactory factory, PagedList.Config config) {
        this.factory = factory;
        this.config = config;

        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);


        networkState = Transformations.switchMap(factory.getDataSource(), source -> {
                    Timber.d("network status get");
                    return source.getNetworkState();
                }
        );
    }

    public void getNews(String courseId, String studentId) {
        //Newss = repo.getNewss(auth, courseId, studentId, 0, 20, "android");
        factory.prepareData(courseId, studentId);
        newslist = new LivePagedListBuilder<>(factory, config).setFetchExecutor(executor).build();
    }

    public void refresh() {
        factory.getDataSource().getValue().invalidate();
    }

    public LiveData<PagedList<News>> getNews() {
        return newslist;
    }

    public LiveData<Resource.Status> getNetworkState() {
        return networkState;
    }
```

I think, my problem may be mismatch my datasource use case and my [datasource type](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/data#choose-data-source-type).So PageList doesn't work properly as we expected.

Comment: not quite sure but can u please change the %s to %d ... and check

Comment: Thanks you for answering. I tried.But I thinks it doesn't deal with my situation.

Comment: Can you post your Factory class

Comment: @Ümañgßürmån I updated

Comment: can you add your `ViewModel` ?

Comment: @ZwalPyaeKyaw updated!

Answer (score 3):

According to Android Paging Library Doc, You should call Api synchronous !
If you use RxRetrofit just remove observeOn() and subscribeOn() to run api on current thread that paging library use .
I tested it and it works fine for me .

Comment: Thank you!. It worked. However, It respond only one time to observer( currently  `viewModel.getNews().observe(this, news -> {
                    Timber.d("news size is %s",news.size());// **news size is 20**
                   //.....
                });`. The things I need is , when i scrolled the list, it **should show** ,40, 60, and so on ..

Comment: Wow, thanks man. This was causing my recycler to not show results until I touched the screen. I removed `observeOn() and subscribeOn()` and used an `Executor` with the `LivePagedListBuilder` and it worked like charm. `PageList` is a delicate class to work with.